# Webview in Android which works in 4.2+ and not in 2.3.3

Tags: android, webview, android-2.3-gingerbread

Application which works in Android 4.2.2 using webview javascriptInterface which is not working in Android 2.3.3.

It has targetSdkVersion="19"

and Build property as 4.2

I have created emulator with 2.3.3 and Device 3.7" WVGA.

OnCreate Here -

```
@JavascriptInterface
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    vWebview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.vWebview);
    btnView = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnView);
    txtView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtView);

    vWebview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
    vWebview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

    try {
        if ("2.3".equals(Build.VERSION.RELEASE)) {
         javascriptInterfaceBroken = true;
        }
        } catch (Exception e) {
        // Ignore, and assume user javascript interface is working correctly.
        }

        // Add javascript interface only if it's not broken
        if (!javascriptInterfaceBroken) {
            vWebview.addJavascriptInterface(new JScriptInterface(),
                    "AndroidFunction");
        }



    WebSettings websetting = vWebview.getSettings();
    websetting.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    Log.d("Main", "Called");
    vWebview.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/sample.html");
    btnView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            //vWebview.loadUrl("javascript:showAndroidToast('Hello')");
            try{
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    vWebview.loadUrl("javascript:showAndroidToast('Hello')");
                }
            });
        }
        catch(Exception ee){
            Log.d("Exception", "Called" + ee.toString());

        }
        }
    });

}
```

JsInterface -

```
public class JScriptInterface {

    public JScriptInterface() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }



    public void showToast(String toast) {
        try{
        Log.d("JS", "Called" + toast);
        // txtView.setText(toast);
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, toast, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        catch(Exception ee){
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, ee.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 

        }
    }



}
```

Comment: Set webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

Comment: Hi , I have Enabled javascript as well as @javascriptInterface also. I am unable to post code. And i don't Knw to post here.

Comment: Follow this to post your code http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

We will be blind in thinking without your code..

Answer (score 2):

I think you might have bumped into [this known issue](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=12987). And here's how to work around it: [Handling Android 2.3 WebView’s broken AddJavascriptInterface](http://www.jasonshah.com/handling-android-2-3-webviews-broken-addjavascriptinterface/)

Credits to the [original poster here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9681548/375929)

*In the future, consider describing your issues in more details.  "which is not working" does not give any idea of the problem, so I just googled "javascriptinterface 2.3.3" -- then again, you could have done it yourself.*

**UPD**
You need to put the methods from the workaround as overrides to your `WebViewClient`.
For your code, it should look something like this:

```
vWebview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());

try {
   if ("2.3".equals(Build.VERSION.RELEASE)) {
      javascriptInterfaceBroken = true;
   }
} catch (Exception e) {
   // Ignore, and assume user javascript interface is working correctly.
}
// Add javascript interface only if it's not broken
if (!javascriptInterfaceBroken) {
    vWebview.addJavascriptInterface(new JScriptInterface(),
            "AndroidFunction");
}

if (!javaScriptInterfaceBroken) vWebview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
else {
    vWebview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        // And here you put the code from the article
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) { ... }

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) { ... }
    });
}
```

Comment: Hi, I am new to this, where to add this one onPageFinished(). In MainActivity or Interface. Both Ask me to Remove @override as Warning.

Comment: @IvanBartsov Thanks for your help, but I still dont know how to use the code. 1) What is that `finishLoading();` call at `onPageFinished`? 2) I dont get the construction of the `handleGingerbreadStupidity` Can you explain what is each of those lines? When I load the URL usually I do the following `mWebview.loadUrl("javascript:init('" + getArguments().getString(KEY_ARG_JSON_WALDBRAND) + "')");` Is that the method that I have to write there or is the one that will be called when the user clicks on the screen?

Comment: 3) Regarding the invocation through reflection, again, I am lost about which function should be called. I am inside Fragment, that contains the class JavaScriptInterface that acts as interface. Should I have `sMethod = WaldbrandgefahrMapFragment.class.getMethod(function, new Class[] { String.class });` or what? Maybe its because I dont know js and the person that made that part is not available now, but I am finding this quite difficult.

Answer (score 0):

Kindly check in devices instead of Emulator. When i checked in Android 2.3.6 its worked well. Unfortunately i didn't get any 2.3.3 device which same as our emulator. If anyone have the device, Kindly check and Confirm me. Thanks a lot for the valuable comments.